# greedy-but-not-too-greedy regex: need to exclude last occurrence of optional character

Tags: regex

*(it must be something trivial and answered many times already - but I can't formulate the right search query, sorry!)*

From the text like `prefix start.then.123.some-more.text. All the rest` I need to extract `start.then.123.some-more.text` - i.e. string that has no spaces, have periods in the middle and **may have or not the trailing period** (and that trailing period should **not** be included). I struggle to build a regex that would catch both cases:
`prefix (start[0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+)\..*` - this works correctly only if there's a trailing period,
`prefix (start[0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+)\.?.*` - I thought adding `?` after `\.` will make it optional - but it doesn't...

P.S. My environment is MS VBA script, I'm using `CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")` - but I guess the question is relevant to other regex engines as well.

Comment: Just use `prefix (start\S*)\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to include “prefix” you can use:

```
(?<=prefix )\S*?(?=\.?\s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hrz7LX/1)

**EDIT:**

Even simpler, without lookbehinds or lookaheads, if you're using capturing groups anyway:

```
prefix (\S*\w)
```

This will stop at the last letter, number, or underscore. If you want to be able to capture a hyphen as the last character, you can change `\w` above to `[\w-]`.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hrz7LX/3)

Comment: Thanks @jdaz! So, there's no way to solve this without using lookahead?

Comment: P.S. as for the "prefix" - oddly, `vbscript.regexp` does not support lookbehinds (though lookaheads are supported), so I wrapped in another pair of parentheses instead: `prefix (\S*?(?=\.?\s))` - that worked

Answer (score 1):

You could match prefix, and use a capturing group to first match chars A-Za-z0-9.

Then you can repeat the previous pattern in a group preceded by either a `.` or `-` using a character class.

```
prefix ([0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[.-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)+)
```

In parts

- `prefix`  Match literally
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed chars
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[.-][0-9a-zA-Z]+` match either a `.` or `-` and again match 1+ times any of the listed chars
  - `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a dot or hyphen
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ipxi0J/1)

If the value in the capturing group should begin with `start`:

```
prefix (start(?:[.-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRxzmM/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the explanation! (marked jdaz answer as a solution because it's simpler, but yours is very helpful too, and very educative)